# Insert performance tuning

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, oracle

Currently we are selecting data from one `database` and inserting it into a backup database(`SQL SERVER`).

This data always contains more than 15K records in one select.
  We are using Enumeration to iterate over the data selected.

We are using `JDBC PreparedStatement` to insert data as:

```
    Enumeration values = ht.elements(); -- ht is HashTable containing selected data.
        while(values.hasMoreElements())
        {
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert query");
                            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }
```

I am not sure if this is the correct or efficient way to do the faster insert.

For inserting 10k rows it takes near about 30 min or more.
Is there any efficient way to make it fast?
*Note*: Not using any indexes on the table.

Comment: Look into batching with `PreparedStatement` and make sure that autocommit is off.

Comment: Are you using both Oracle and MS SQL Server here?

Comment: Target tables should not have any index. It would help in faster insertion.

Comment: Try [batch insert](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/)

Comment: Check about `DELAYED_DURABILITY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a batch insert, but commit after a few entris, don't try to send all 10K at once.  Try investigating to get the best size, it' a trade off to memory vs network trips.

```
Connection connection = new getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
int i = 0;

for (String query : queries) {
    statement.addBatch("insert query");
    if ((i++ % 500) == 0) {
         // Do an execute now and again, don't send too many at once
        statement.executeBatch(); 
    }
}

statement.executeBatch();
statement.close();
connection.close();
```

Also, from your code I'm not sure what you are doing, but use paramaterised queries rather than sending 10K insert statements as text.  Something like:

```
String q= "INSERT INTO data_table (id) values (?)";
Connection connection = new getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(q);

for (Data d: data) {     
    ps.setString(1, d.getId());
    ps.addBatch();
}

ps.executeBatch();
ps.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using insert statements as text, is using paramaterised queries will make it efficient? Regarding batch insert which "queries" you mean to say as I am using single insert query in a loop?

Comment: Yes, a paramaterised  query will be more efficient as the query is only sent once per batch this will be give a smaller payload to send.  Plus the DB server need not parse each query separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert all the values in one sql command:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( V1, V2 ), ( V3, V4 ), .......
```

You may also insert the values by bulks of 500 records, for example, if the query would become very big. It is not efficient at all to insert on row per statement remotely (using a connection). Another solution is to do the inserts using a stored procedure. You just pass the values to it as parameters.

Here is how you can do it using the `INSERT` command above:

```
 Enumeration values = ht.elements(); -- ht is HashTable containing selected data.
 int i=0;
 String sql="";

    while(values.hasMoreElements())
    {
            sql+="(" + values + ")"; //better use StringBuffer here
            i++;
            if(i % 500 == 0) {
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert query "+sql);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
                sql="";
            }
            else
                sql += " , ";
    }
```

Comment: I am using insert query exactly as u suggested. How can we use bulk insert? Plz suggest

Comment: Keep in mind that this method has limitation of 1000 values in the insert statement.

Comment: @nilFi I updated the answer. In brief, you create one insert statement for each 500 records and execute it.